# ExpandableListView - getChildAt() returns the wrong View

Tags: android, view, expandablelistview

So I have this ExpandableListView that should highlight the groups that are clicked.
I do this by running

```
eList.getChildAt(eList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(i))).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

whereas i is the index of the group's view that was clicked.

However, as you can see in the image provided here, it only returns the correct view when I'm traversing upwards the list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaAkS.gif

I should note that when I have the onGroupClick() set to return false, getChildAt returns the correct value and the correct group view is highlighted. However, having it set to false would result in groups opening twice when clicked(twice as many child elements), as I'm "manually" collapsing/expanding the groups as the /searchterm/ changes.

For debugging purposes I tried to highlight the getChildAt(1) when any group was clicked. The "1" group was highlighted in all cases except for when I clicked the "0" group, whereas the last group was highlighted instead.

Classes can be found below

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> categoryName;
    List<String> categoryList;
    ExpandableListView eList;
    CategoryAdapter adapter;
    EditText textField;
    int lastHighlightParent = -1;
    int lastHighlightChild = -1;
    int groupToHighlight;
    String prevDirName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Laboration 2");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTextField);
        textField.setText("€/€");
        eList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        textField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                if (lastHighlightChild != -1 && lastHighlightParent != -1) {
                    eList.getChildAt(
                            eList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                                    .getPackedPositionForChild(
                                            lastHighlightParent,
                                            lastHighlightChild)))
                            .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    lastHighlightChild = -1;
                    lastHighlightParent = -1;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < eList.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    eList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }

                boolean match = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                            String tempPath = "/" + adapter.getGroupText(i) + "/"
                                    + adapter.getChildText(i, j);
                            if (tempPath.startsWith(s.toString())
                                    && s.toString().length() > 1 && match != true) {
                                groupToHighlight = eList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                                        .getPackedPositionForGroup(i));
                                eList.getChildAt(eList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                                        .getPackedPositionForGroup(i))).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                                textField.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                match = true;
                            } else if (s.toString().equals("/") || s.length() == 0) {
                                textField.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            } else {
                                if (match != true) {
                                    eList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(
                                            Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                    textField.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                }
                            }

                    }
                }

                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                    if (s.toString().startsWith(
                            "/" + adapter.getGroupText(i) + "/")) {
                        if (!eList.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                            eList.expandGroup(i);
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                            if (s.toString().endsWith(
                                    adapter.getChildText(i, j))) {
                                eList.getChildAt(
                                        eList.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                                                .getPackedPositionForChild(i, j)))
                                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                lastHighlightParent = i;
                                lastHighlightChild = j;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        eList.collapseGroup(i);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

        });

        eList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                textField.setText("/" + adapter.getGroupText(groupPosition)
                        + "/"
                        + adapter.getChildText(groupPosition, childPosition));
                return false;
            }

        });
        eList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {

                if (adapter.getGroupText(groupPosition).equals(prevDirName)
                        && eList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    eList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                } else {

                    textField.setText("/" + adapter.getGroupText(groupPosition)
                            + "/");
                }

                prevDirName = adapter.getGroupText(groupPosition);


                return true;
            }

        });

        categoryName = listData();
        categoryList = new ArrayList<String>(categoryName.keySet());
        adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryName, categoryList);
        eList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> categoryDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> drinks = new ArrayList<String>();
        drinks.add("Tea");
        drinks.add("Coffee");
        drinks.add("Water");
        drinks.add("Lemonade");
        drinks.add("Beer");

        List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
        animals.add("Cat");
        animals.add("Dog");
        animals.add("Dromedary");
        animals.add("Boar");

        List<String> vegetables = new ArrayList<String>();      
        vegetables.add("Lettuce");
        vegetables.add("Tomato");
        vegetables.add("Spinach");
        vegetables.add("Cucumber");

        List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
        colors.add("Blue");
        colors.add("Red");
        colors.add("Pink");
        colors.add("Brown");

        List<String> sodas = new ArrayList<String>();
        sodas.add("Cola");
        sodas.add("Pepsi");
        sodas.add("Fanta");
        sodas.add("7-up");

        categoryDetail.put("Animals", animals);
        categoryDetail.put("Vegetables", vegetables);
        categoryDetail.put("Colors", colors);
        categoryDetail.put("Sodas", sodas);
        categoryDetail.put("Drinks", drinks);

        return categoryDetail;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        textField.setText(item.getTitle());
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> categories;
    private List<String> categoryList;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context m_context, HashMap<String, List<String>> m_categories, List<String> m_categoryList){
        this.context = m_context;
        this.categories = m_categories;
        this.categoryList = m_categoryList;
    }

    public String getGroupText(int groupPosition){
        Object[] keys = this.categories.keySet().toArray();
        return (String) keys[groupPosition];
    }

    public String getChildText(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        Object[] keys = this.categories.keySet().toArray();
        return (String) categories.get(keys[groupPosition]).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return categories.get(categoryList.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return categoryList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
        return categories.get(categoryList.get(parent)).get(child);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int parent, int child){
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        String groupTitle = (String) getGroup(parent);
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parentView, false);
        }
        TextView parentTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
        parentTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        parentTextView.setText(groupTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int parent, int child,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {

        String childTitle = (String) getChild(parent, child);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflat = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parentView, false);
        }

        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_txt);
        childTextView.setText(childTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```